# Spring Roo and the bundleSymbolicName switch

Tags: spring-roo, spring-surf

I can't install the surf tools because of a ridiculously under documented and very required switch "--bundleSymbolicName".  I cannot for the life of me find anything online that helps me with this.  The spring documentation is almost completely silent except for a basic "yep, it's required" buried in the appendix somewhere.  Anyone have any idea where to point me.

It throws me this error.

```
You must specify option 'bundleSymbolicName' for this command
```

The Spring surf tutorial mentions nothing about this that I can see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the answer appears to be use roo 1.0.2 instead of 1.1: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=97794

Worked for me.